# Multiple joins in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, query-optimization

I have this SP with more than 10tables involved. In the underlined lines, there is a table AllData which is being joined 3times because of the fieldname in the where clause.

Any suggestions on how to handle this complex query better will be greatly appreciated. Mostly, to avoid the multiple times I am joining AllData(with alias names ad1, adl2, adl3). This could affect the performance.

Here is the sp

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[StoredProc1]
AS
select  case when pd.Show_Photo = '1,1,1'
             then i.id
             else null
        end as thumbimage,
        t1.FPId,
        'WebProfile' as profiletype,
        mmbp.Name as Name,
        t1.Age,
        t1.Height,
        adl.ListValue as AlldataValue1,
        adl2.ListValue as AlldataValue2,
        adl3.ListValue as AlldataValue3,
        c.CName,
        ed.ELevel,
        ed.EDeg,
        NEWID()
from Table2  mmbp, Table3  u
join Table1 t1 on t1.Pid = u.Pid
left join Table4 mmb on t1.Pid= mmb.Pid 
join table5 i on t1.Pid = i.Pid 
join table6 pd on t1.Pid = pd.Pid
join table7 ed on t1.Pid = ed.Pid
join table8 c on t1.xxx= c.xxx
join AllData  adl on t1.xxx = adl.ListKey 
join AllData adl2 on b.ms = adl2.ListKey
join AllData adl3 on b.Diet = adl3.ListKey
where adl.FieldName=xxx and
      adl2.FieldName='ms' and
      adl3.FieldName='Diet' and 
      ------
```

Comment: Is there a join condition between Table2 (alias mmbp) and any of the other tables in the omitted conditions in the `where` clause? Also, can you include the rest of the query, and the query plan when you run the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I note that you appear to have a cartesian join between Table2 and Table3 - unless one of these tables is very small, this is likely to drastically affect performance. I suggest explicitly joining Table2 to one of the other tables in the query, to improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could try is moving the where conditions into the joins

```
join AllData ad1 on t1.xxx = ad1.ListKey AND ad1.FieldName = xxx
join AllData ad2 on b.ms = adl2.ListKey AND ad2.FieldName = 'ms'
join AllData ad3 on b.Diet = adl3.ListKey AND ad3.FieldName = 'Diet'
```

This would give better performance as the join size would be limited to only the records you want. To do this all in one join you could `join AllData ad on (t1.xxx = ad.ListKey AND ad.FieldName = xxx) OR (b.ms = ad.ListKey AND ad.FieldName = 'ms')...`. The issue with this option is you no longer have distinct columns for ad1, ad2, etc.

Comment: 'This would give better performance as the join size would be limited to only the records you want' - moving predicates from the where clause to the join clause will not effect the execution plan generated (inner join in this case) - try it out yourself

Comment: @JCooper: "are unlikely to affect the execution plan generated" would be a better way of putting it, than "will not effect the execution plan generated" - unless you yourself wrote the SQLServer optimizer, and know what it will do in *every* possible circumstance? (Given that the OP has not included the whole of the query...)

Comment: @Mark Bannister - indeed I did not write the optimizer. The point is that logically they are the same query. In the case of an inner join, it doesn't matter if the join condition is specified in the join predicate or in the where clause and are the logically the same. Left joins are the only time it matters where you specify the join condition. With that said, they are logically the same exact thing and I would say it is highly unlikely that the optimizer would generate two different plans.

Comment: @Mark Bannister - just curious, you made a point that "the OP has not included the whole of the query". Is there a scenario you know of that would cause the optimizer to generate a different plan? I can think of none,

Comment: @JCooper: Logically, you are correct, but I have known optimizers to behave in unexpected ways.